# Login user after email activation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing asp.net MVC web application. After user registration, an `email` containing validation code will send to his/her `email` address.

I'm trying to login user automatically after `email` validation but if fact I only have `userId`, and hashed `password`.

Comment: You can't do that. Just redirect the user to the login page after saying him that its registration is confirmed.

Comment: Are you using something like ASP.NET Membership Provider to authenticate or are you writing your own custom auth layer?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Membership Provider

Comment: you should not do that. if someone got the link they can do anything without know password. Example in case they type mistake in email